# How to fix a code where it is just printing to the pervious file not the correct file?

Tags: perl

I have created a program with the purpose of creating separate files for each trait within a database.

The problem is that when we created this, the statements work as if it does not exist create new file, if it already place it in to the pervious file.

I would like it be placed in the pervious file with that trait.

Code is below

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @traitarray;
my $traitarray;
my $input;
my %traithash;
my $t_out;
my $TRAIT;
my $SNPS;
my $PVALUE;
my $PUBMEDID;
my $CHR_POS;
my $CHR_ID;

open( $input, "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-31.tsv" ) || die();

while ( <$input> ) {

    @traitarray = split( /\t/ );

    $TRAIT      = $traitarray[7];
    print "$TRAIT\t";

    $SNPS     = $traitarray[21];
    $PVALUE   = $traitarray[27];
    $PUBMEDID = $traitarray[1];
    $CHR_POS  = $traitarray[12];
    $CHR_ID   = $traitarray[11];

    $PVALUE =~ s/^[^E]*E//;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/ /_/;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/:/-/;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/\//-/;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/*/-/;

    print "$TRAIT\t$SNPS\t$PVALUE\n";

    if ( $PVALUE <= -8 ) {
        if ( !exists $traithash{$TRAIT} ) {
            open( $t_out, ">outputFiles/" . $TRAIT . ".txt" ) || die();
            print $t_out "$SNPS\t $traitarray[27] \t $PUBMEDID \t$CHR_POS \t $CHR_ID \t \n";
            $traithash{$TRAIT} = 1;
            push( @traitarray, $TRAIT );
        }
        else {
            print $t_out "$SNPS\t $traitarray[27] \t $PUBMEDID \t$CHR_POS \t $CHR_ID \t \n";
        }
    }
}

foreach ( $traitarray ) {
    close;
}
```

Comment: Check that your `open` is working properly:  `open my $t_out, '>', "outputFiles/$TRAIT.txt" or die $!`

Comment: it is @Borodin I will include that in to post to clarify, but it is opening.

Comment: Why not close the previous file when you're done with it?

Comment: Because there may be another trait within the database that belongs in the file @JimDavis

Comment: @Michaela Ah, ok. I'd probably reverse that `if/else` block and change the condition to something like `if ($t_out = $traithash{$TRAIT}) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like it's based on the sort of thing I would write, and I suspect you have tried to reuse an answer to a previous question without understanding it

Your hash should contain file handles indexed by the value of `$trait`, and your code should check to see if there is already a file open for this trait before creating a new one

I think this should work for you

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input, "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-31.tsv" or die $!;

my %trait_fh;

while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;
    my @traits = split /\t/;

    my ($pubmedid, $trait, $chr_id, $chr_pos, $snps, $pvalue) = @traits[1,7,11,12,21,27];
    $pvalue =~ s/^[^e]*e//;
    $trait =~ tr| :/*|_-|;

    local ($,, $\) = ("\t", "\n");
    print $trait, $snps, $pvalue;

    if ( $pvalue <= -8 ) {

        my $file = "outputfiles/$trait.txt";
        my $out_fh;

        if ( $out_fh = $trait_fh{$trait} ) {
            print qq{Reusing file "$file"};
        }
        else {
            open $out_fh, '>', $file or die qq{Failed to open "$file" for output: $!};
            print qq{File "$file" created};
            $trait_fh{$trait} = $out_fh;
        }

        print $out_fh $snps, $pvalue, $pubmedid, $chr_pos, $chr_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Borodin , but it now will only print one trait per file, and I am unsure as to why

Comment: @Michaela: I have tried it with some test data and it prints multiple lines to the files if tehre are matching traits. Have you run the program exactly as it is?

Comment: @Michaela: I've added some trace output to the program so that you can see when it's creating a new file or reusing an existing one

Comment: I receive an error at line 6 with the "say" feature, what is that doing @Borodin I am running the program exactly as is

Comment: @Michaela: Then you are running a *very* old version of Perl. I've changed it again so that it doesn't use `say`

Comment: I  downloaded it last month off the perl website @Borodin

Comment: Thank you but I am now receiving syntax errors at lines 26 and 30

Comment: @Borodin Is `use feature 'say'` the default now?

Comment: @JimDavis: No. You have to declare that you need any feature, either with `use feature 'say'` or with `use v5.10`. Using a version number enable all features available in that version of Perl

Comment: @Michaela: I missed a couple of calls to `say`. Try now

Comment: @Borodin Ah, I saw your answer between edits, without `feature` but with `say`.

Comment: I received the same syntax error at lines 26 and 30 near"sayqq...$file} and "sayqq... created}"  @Borodin

Comment: @Michaela: There are no calls to `say` any more. Try again

Comment: There is only one trait for file again @Borodin

Comment: @Michaela: I can't help you unless I see your data. Can you put it on pastebin.com so that I can see what you are seeing?

Comment: @Michaela: Does it generate the `Reusing file "..."` messages?

Comment: no @Borodin , was able to figure it out it was a question of ">" vs ">>" I will post it below thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

By closing, then reopening and adding on to the file using ">>" the issue was able to be solved.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl



use strict;
use warnings;

my @traitarray;
my $traitarray;
my $input ;
my %traithash ;
my $traithash;
my $t_out ;
my $TRAIT;
my $SNPS;
my $PVALUE;
my $PUBMEDID;
my $CHR_POS; 
my $CHR_ID;
open ($input, "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-31.tsv") || die () ;

while(<$input>) {
    @traitarray = split (/\t/);
    $TRAIT = $traitarray[7]; 
    $SNPS = $traitarray[21];
    $PVALUE =$traitarray[27];
    $PUBMEDID =$traitarray[1];
    $CHR_POS =$traitarray[12];
    $CHR_ID =$traitarray[11];
    $PVALUE =~ s/^[^E]*E//;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/ /_/ ;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/:/-/ ;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/\//-/ ;
    $TRAIT =~ tr/*/-/ ;

    if ($PVALUE <= -8) {
        if (!exists $traithash {$TRAIT}) {
            open ($t_out, ">outputFiles/".$TRAIT.".txt") || die () ;
            print $t_out "$SNPS\t $traitarray[27] \t $PUBMEDID \t$CHR_POS \t $CHR_ID \t \n"; 
            $traithash {$TRAIT} = 1 ;
            push (@traitarray, $TRAIT);  
            close $t_out; 
    }
        else {
            open ($t_out, ">>outputFiles/".$TRAIT.".txt") || die () ;
            print $t_out "$SNPS\t $traitarray[27] \t $PUBMEDID \t$CHR_POS \t $CHR_ID \t \n";  
            close $t_out;
        }
    }
}
```